# What are the commands to see and edit the user's information? after to use adduser

Tags: users, user-management, adduser, user-profile

I read these tutorials:

- [How to create a user account on Ubuntu Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-a-user-account-on-ubuntu-linux/)
- [How to Add and Delete Users on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-and-delete-users-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

When is used the `adduser` command appears in the process:

```
Changing the user information for username
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: 
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n]
```

For obvious reasons is possible leave empty or write outdated data, so, the reason of this post:

- What are the commands to *see* and *edit* the user's information?

About the "*see*" approach should show again the same structure

```
    Full Name []: 
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []:
```

Of course, showing the data according with either the data created or the latest data update to know what is correct or not.

Comment: That data is typically called GECOS data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `man chsh chfn getent;man 5 passwd`. The first two change the shell and the full name,  the third retrieves a user's info. The fourth explains the fields. `getent`, along with `| cut -d: -f#` can easily extract individual fields. Read `man cut`.